# Dispatching an action twice removes a different state from the store

Tags: angular, ngrx

- I have a store with a `user` state and a `transactions` state, and
- I have an action called `this.store.dispatch( new actions.Query());`

When I navigate to the page I dispatch the `Query()` action in `ngOnInit()` which calls an Effect that retrieves transactions from my database and adds them to the store.

This works fine the first time the page loads however navigating away from this page and back again removes the `user` state from my store.

I have determined that this function call is the culprit as removing it ensures the user state remains in the store.

How can I fix this, or, could anyone explain a good way to debug this? I am struggling to see anywhere that would override the entire state of my store.

Here is my ngOnInit call

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.transactions = this.store.select(fromTransaction.selectAll);
    this.store.dispatch( new actions.Query());
  }
```

Here is my Transactions Effect

```js
    @Effect()
    query$: Observable<any> = this.actions$.pipe(
      // listens for when the query action is called
      ofType(transactionActions.QUERY),
      // takes the action and returns a reference of the database with a snapshot of changes
      switchMap(action => {
          return this.firestore.collection<Transaction>('transactions', ref => {
              return ref;
          })
          .snapshotChanges();
      }),
      mergeMap(actions => actions),
      map(action => {
          return {
              type: `[TRANSACTION] ${action.type}`,
              payload: {
                  ...action.payload.doc.data(),
                  id: action.payload.doc.id
              }
          };
      })
    );
```

Here is my transaction reducer:

```js
export function TransactionReducer(
    state: State = initialState,
    action: actions.TransactionActions
) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actions.ADDED:
          return transactionAdapter.addOne(action.payload, state);
      case actions.MODIFIED:
          return transactionAdapter.updateOne({
              id: action.payload.id,
              changes: action.payload
          }, state);
      case actions.REMOVED:
          console.log(action.payload);
          return transactionAdapter.removeOne(action.payload.id, state);
      default:
          return state;
    }
}
```

Here is the State interface:

```
export interface AppState {
    transaction: Transaction[];
    user: User | null;
}
```

Here is the User Reducer

```
export function userReducer(state: User = defaultUser, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case userActions.GET_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true };

    case userActions.AUTHENTICATED:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload, loading: false };

    case userActions.NOT_AUTHENTICATED:
        return { ...state, ...defaultUser, loading: false};

    case userActions.GOOGLE_LOGIN:
        return { ...state, loading: true};

    case userActions.AUTH_ERROR:
        return { ...state, ...action.payload, loading: false};

    case userActions.LOGOUT:
        return { ...state, loading: true};
  }
}
```

And here is my StoreModule import in `app.module.ts`

```
  StoreModule.forRoot({
      transaction: TransactionReducer,
      user: userReducer
    }),
```

Comment: Could you show the `State` interface as well?

Comment: Might you also add reducer and actions of the `user`? Looks like there's intersection between them.

Comment: I've added the user reducer, and the State interface as requested

Comment: Your reducers should have a `default:` in `switch`, returning a new state (something like `default: return {...state}` or you'll end up erasing everything.

Answer (score 1):

Add a default in your switch. Remember that a reducer **must** return a new state and it receives all the actions all the time. If a reducer doesn't return anything, because the action doesn't match any `case`, it's like it's returning `undefined` as your new state.

So:

```js
export function userReducer(state: User = defaultUser, action: Action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case userActions.GET_USER:
      return { ...state, loading: true };

    case userActions.AUTHENTICATED:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload, loading: false };

    case userActions.NOT_AUTHENTICATED:
        return { ...state, ...defaultUser, loading: false};

    case userActions.GOOGLE_LOGIN:
        return { ...state, loading: true};

    case userActions.AUTH_ERROR:
        return { ...state, ...action.payload, loading: false};

    case userActions.LOGOUT:
        return { ...state, loading: true};
  }

  return {...state};
}
```

BTW, be careful with the spread operator. It returns only a shallow copy of your state. If you have complex objects stored in the state, you'll be breaking a golden rule: immutability. I'd recommend you use [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction) to build a new state whenever you need it.

Comment: If you like immer, take a look at https://github.com/timdeschryver/ngrx-etc